# Unable to login using request.Session().post

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been unable to successfully get past this webpages login screen using python. I have tried requests.Session().get and Selenium but currently I cannot even using selenium due to other errors.

If I could get past the login using requests I would prefer this. My code is as follows:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.chartmill.com/login.php', data=dict(
    username='username',
    password='password',
    ))
```

I would appreciate any help because I cannot figure any of this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

import requests
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data={
    'username':'username',
    'password':"password",
    }
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.chartmill.com/chartmill-rest/member/login', data=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)
judge= s.get('https://www.chartmill.com/account.php?o=74375').text.find(username)
print(judge)
```

Is work.

Comment: If you succeed,close the question so that  i can get the "BADGES" and tell others  What is the practicable way for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The form also submits `submitID=1` along with `username` and `password`. Try:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.chartmill.com/login.php', data=dict(
    username='username',
    password='password',
    submitID=1
    ))
```

Comment: Hello, I was still unable to get past the login page using this code.

Comment: For some reason that website has now switched to an AJAX-based login since I tried out your URL yesterday, so `https://www.chartmill.com/login.php` no longer works.